# Is there a lightweight GUI protocol like X11 that works well over ssh?

Tags: ssh, x11, xorg, x11-forwarding

Remote X11 apps are slow unless running over a Gigabit LAN, and I'm looking for a protocol somewhere between ANSI escape codes and Postscript programs, that enables rendering graphical UI widgets and windows sent by a remote process over SSH to the local X11 server.

Can I somehow seamlessly redirect connections from remote GUI processes to a local process that processes these Postscript-like requests and outputs X11 requests to the local server ? Normal X11 forwarded connections go directly to the local $DISPLAY socket which expects verbose, high-bandwidth X11 requests.

I think Plan 9 had something like this but I can't find any reference at the moment. VS Code also has a clever approach where it serves HTML+JS from the SSH remote.

Comment: Neither ANSI escape codes nor Postscript is a protocol. I do not really understand the context/environment that you are asking about. What does your application do itself and what does it expect from a server?

Comment: I don't see how VS Code's approach is related to this; that just communicates with the VS Code server over SSH, all the rendering is done by the client (using Electron).